# What type of navigation in React works well with login authentication?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, navigation

I wonder what type of navigation works well with login authentication? Right now i use conditional rendering for certain pages or components to display and through

```
if (this.state.loggedIn) {
    return <UI loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} showUser=
{this.state.showUser} logout={this.logout.bind(this)} />; 

            };
```

i can render something after the validation. What would it look like if i wanted to render a couple of more different pages? Should i put a state on each page that will change on onclicks and cause the app to render desired page?

Thank you lads

Comment: If i get this right, you need to take look at [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

Comment: ive tried router but would it technically be secure to use <Link> in said app?

Comment: Why it can be insecure? Also there's no mention about security-ish solution is preferred

Comment: i dunno man i know very little about this, would linking be the best method of navigation then?

Comment: I can only say that routers like react-router and ui-router are commonly used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue which nearly every modern application must tackle. Because of this, many libraries have already solved these issues for you. Take this code for example which uses react-router:

In my example I am showing you what the routes would look like in a routes.js file and then a separate file for what the acl would look like. The acl is a function which is passed into the onEnter of each route you want to protect. You can call it anything you like.

**routes.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { hashHistory, Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import { acl } from './util/acl-util';

import AppContainer from './containers/app-container';
import DashboardPage from './pages/dashboard-page';

export default class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={AppContainer}>
          {/* NON-AUTH ROUTES */}
          <Route
            path="login"
            components={{
              main: LoginPage,
              aside: null,
              header: this.getHeader,
            }}
          />

          {/* AUTH-REQUIRED ROUTES */}
          <Route
            onEnter={acl}
            path="dashboard"
            components={{ main: DashboardPage }}
          />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**acl-util.js**

```js
import { hasAuth } from './auth-util';

export function acl(nextState, replace) {
  const { pathname, search } = nextState.location;

  if (!hasAuth(theState)) {
    window.alert(
      'Please Log in!'
    );
    replace(`/login?loginRedirect=${encodeURIComponent(pathname + search)}`);
  }
}
```

I threw this example together from cutting out part of my code that won't apply directly to this concept - and therefore this code won't run as is. You'll need to define your pages, and set up a store etc.

You'd need to define a hasAuth function which can look into your state and determine whether a user is authenticated. For my hasAuth function I am looking for a jwt token and parsing the date, if the date is still in the future, I know they are still authed and any subsequent rest api calls will work.

I know you weren't asking for a certain library, but I recommend this because the app I took this code from has dozens of routes and the acl function also implements a role matrix which looks at what a user can and cannot do based on their jwt token. Our application is pretty massive and this approach keeps it organized.

Without having something like react-router, you're right, you'd need to manually manage which page is showing and manually check for auth state in each component or make a parent component to do it. In my example the "parent component to manage it" is react-router and my onEnter method called acl. In traditional applications acl stands for access control list - you can expand the code in whichever way you like.

**edit:**

as someone mentioned in a comment about . Your frontend application is only as secure as the backend service it is grabbing data from or posting data to. In my example, the react code attempts to mirror the auth state in the jwt token. But, at the end of the day, your real security will only be provided by your back end services. Just because the frontend thinks a user can be logged in, shouldn't mean the backend should assume they are - you need backend authentication since all frontend application state can be modified by technical users.

Comment: That's a very solid answer there mate. I will have to go through it and try to apply it to my own project.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! the nice thing about using this approach and using onEnter is you can do anything you want in there, and react-router provides you with a `replace` method that you can call to change routes if you want. The application I took this code from displays alerts and does other magical stuff too. Also, this application uses redux to manage the global state. You might want to look into that and decide if it will help.